# How to resolve "API request failed: Unknown Error" with "connection error" on a GET API with a JSON payload?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, web, unity-webgl

Below is the code for the function that handles API call

```cs
    public IEnumerator getItemAddress_GET(string json_data)//incomplete!!
    {
        this.response = null;
        UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest("https://___.com/___/___/___/___/getItem", "GET");
        //string json_data = "{\"position\":4,\"rack\": 1,\"room\": 1,\"section\": 2,\"zone\":1}";
        byte[] json_raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json_data);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(json_raw);
        request.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/json";
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            response = Utils_Common.API_Response.FAILED;
            if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)       Debug.Log("Connection Error");
            if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)         Debug.Log("Protocol Error");
            if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError)   Debug.Log("Data Processing Error");

            Debug.LogError("API request failed: " + request.error + " || Uploaded Bytes: " + request.uploadedBytes);
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            response = request.downloadHandler.text;
        }
        Debug.Log(response);
        yield return null;
    }
```

The above function is part of a `MonoBehaviour` class with all types of API calls required in the whole project.

The `DB_API` class is added beside the classes that need to make API calls by using

```
    .....
    //class member
    DB_API api_instance;
    .....
    //inside Start()
    this.gameObject.AddComponent<DB_API>();
    this.api_instance = this.gameObject.GetComponent<DB_API>();
    .....
```

The problem revolves around the `WebGL` platform. The project is able to make API calls successfully when I call from inside the `Unity player` OR the `Windows` platform. But when the API call is made through WebGL platform the following error emerges:-

[image: WebGL error]

There are no other errors or network activity during or after the above error.

I have allowed `Insecure Content` in chrome:-
[image: Insecure content: allowed]

I also tried with `https://localhost` instead of `http://localhost`

Is there something I am missing? OR
Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: How exactly do you host the WebGL instance? Is the target URL reachable from there?

Comment: complete sidenote btw you can directly do `api_instance = gameObject.AddComponent<DB_API>();` in a single go

Comment: @derHugo The WebGL instance can access other types of APIs from the same class. Only this specific API returns error.

Comment: Just t confirm are you sure the API is GET? Do you have another sample of a call that does work so we can compare them? Otherwise maybe there is an issue on the API side and not your c# code

Comment: @derHugo As I have mentioned, the calls work from inside the unity when I press play and also from windows build without errors

Comment: `I also tried with https://localhost instead of http://localhost` .. is it actually localhost? could it be a firewall issue?

Comment: @derHugo yes it is localhost, should I update pictures on the post?